# Very basic bootstrap not working

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm learning bootstrap and I have this very simple styling that isn't displaying. I'm going by bootstrap's website for documentation and this should work?

```
@media (min-width:@screen-sm-min) {
    body {
        background-color:red;
    }
}

@media (min-width:@screen-md-min) {
    body {
        background-color:blue;
    }
}

@media (min-width:@screen-lg-min) {
    body {
        background-color:green;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you compiling your site with [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) or just using static CSS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you are compiling your CSS with a [LESS](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#less) compiler then using variables like that will not work. Instead use the actual values, in this case the defaults from Bootstrap would make your CSS look like this:

```
@media (min-width:768px) {
    body {
        background-color:red;
    }
}

@media (min-width:992px) {
    body {
        background-color:blue;
    }
}

@media (min-width:1200px) {
    body {
        background-color:green;
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not using a LESS compiler, is the documentation they have rendered useless unless you use a LESS compiler?

Comment: The documentation is actually pretty excellent in my opinion. You don't have to use a LESS compiler, I have many projects like that. Just remember to use the actual numbers instead of variables.

Comment: I wanted to try using the @screen-lg-min because when I plug in pixel numbers I have a hard time believing half my screen width is 1024px when I'm using a laptop. I assumed that it doesn't interpret it accurately.

Comment: Take a look at the [Bootstrap documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#media-queries-breakpoints) and you can see that `@screen-lg-min` compiles to `@screen-lg` which in turn compiles to `1200px`.

Comment: Does that mean that using bootstrap classes (it looks like LESS) in the html won't work either? i.e. <div class=".col-md-12">Copy</div>

Comment: The class names will work fine just drop the `.` prefix: `<div class="col-md-12">Copy</div>`

Answer (score 0):

Remember when you are using bootstrap the structure is based on a 12 column grid. You have 4 basic media queries that trigger based on the view port.

```
@media (max-width: 767px) so anything between 0px and 767px will use this set of styles.

@media (min-width: 768px) so anything between 768px and 991px will use this set of styles.

@media (min-width: 992px) so anything between 992px and 1199px will use this set of styles.

@media (min-width: 1200px) so anything 1200px or larger will use this set of styles.
```

Columns are written this way.

```
<div class="col-lg-12"></div> the number can be anything from 1-12 based on the number of columns you wish to use.
```

You have 3 column sizes which are as follows:

col-lg- (1-12)
col-md- (1-12)
col-sm- (1-12)
col-xs- (1-12)

Whenever you would like your columns to respond based on the view port you use a combination of sizes.

I hope this helps you out.